# Oracle update using multiple tables

Tags: oracle, sql-update, multiple-tables

Can someone help me with this sql statement to run on Oracle? I am new to Oracle. I tried different ways, but getting syntax error. With this statement I get `Missing SET keyworkd` error, if I remove employee, I get invalid column name for emp_id.

```
update emp_bonus, employee                                                               
set emp_bonus.bonus = '555'                        
where emp_bonus.emp_id = employee.emp_id and emp_bonus.bonus_id  = '101';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a syntax error. 
What do you like to do??

In this case the query would be constructed as follows:

```
UPDATE   EMP_BONUS
   SET   EMP_BONUS.BONUS = '555'
 WHERE   EMP_BONUS.BONUS_ID = '101'
         AND EXISTS (SELECT   'X'
                       FROM   EMPLOYEE
                      WHERE   EMP_BONUS.EMP_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID);
```

Where only update the `BONUS` field when the `ID` **exists** in the `EMPLOYEE` table.

Comment: @user3613050 That's perfect. Anything just ask. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Fernando, what should be the command if I need to change the where clause to EMPLOYEE.RATE_ID = '133' instead of a column from other table (EMP_BONUS.BONUS_ID = '101')?

Comment: Never mind, adding that to the select statement took care of it.

Comment: @user3613050 Only will update more than one time, if any at EMP_BONUS table more than one record with the BONUS_ID = 101